# How to launch and open email client ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-form, mailto

I want to show a pop-up like this [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUGsZ.png) in my react application. In simple words, I want to launch and open the email client in **ReactJs**. I am currently using a simple p tag:

```
 <p className="cnct_email_addr">Email US</p>
```

I know there is a way to use mailto like this:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com">Email Us</a>
```

But I want to know if there is a more reactish-way of doing it. If there is one please let me know.

Answer (score 19):

You can open the `mailto` link using `window`

```
window.open('mailto:email@example.com?subject=Subject&body=Body%20goes%20here')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const Mailto = ({ email, subject, body, children }) => {
  return (
    <a href={`mailto:${email}?subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject) || ''}&body=${encodeURIComponent(body) || ''}`}>{children}</a>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Mailto email="foo@bar.baz" subject="Hello & Welcome" body="Hello world!">
    Mail me!
  </Mailto>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Reference [link](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/react/s/mailto).

Answer (score -3):

You must import this 'Linking'

```
<Button onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:support@example.com?subject=SendMail&body=Description') }
              title="support@example.com" />
```

Comment: This is for react-native. This only works for mobile apps. I need ti for ReactJs for web apps