# How to set mailto into a property of child react.js component

Tags: reactjs, react-component, mailto

I am returning data from API in React.js, one property is 'email' of object 'user'. I would like to be able to click on the email address so a new email window addressed to that user pops up. I want the email address to appear in the 'to' input field.

I would like something like this: `<a href="mailto:user@example.com">user@example.com</a>` but for react.

I have been searching but I found [this solution](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/react/s/mailto), [this solution](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/open+link+to+email+in+react) and [this solution](https://github.com/jasonbellamy/react-mailto) difficult to understand as they are written the old way or they are for react native only.

Someone suggested event [this](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63909032/how-to-launch-and-open-email-client-reactjs) ...but how to apply it inside my component?

```
window.open('mailto:email@example.com?subject=Subject&body=Body%20goes%20here')
```

This is the child component:

```
const UserDetail = ({name, username, email, address, address2, city, phone, website, company, onClick}) => {
 
  return (
    <>
      <DetailCard>    
        <Name>{name}</Name>
        <Data>Username:{username}</Data>
        <Data>E-mail:{email}</Data>
        <Data>Adress:{address}</Data>
        <Data>Adress 2:{address2}</Data>
        <Data>City:{city}</Data>
        <Data>Phone number:{phone}</Data>      
        <Data>Website:{website}</Data>      
        <Data>Company:{company}</Data>
        <Button onClick={onClick}>close</Button>      
      </DetailCard>
    </>
  )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach an `onClick` event handler to the e-mail field:

```
const UserDetail = ({name, username, email, address, address2, city, phone, website, company, onClick}) => {
 
  function onEmailClick() {
      window.open(`mailto:${email}`);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <DetailCard>    
        ...
        <Data onClick={onEmailClick}>E-mail:{email}</Data>
        ...
      </DetailCard>
    </>
  )}
```

Comment: I added the link tag so it looks like a link. But not sure if this solution: <Data onClick={onEmailClick}>E-mail:<a href={email}>{email}</a></Data> plus the const onEmailClick is better than  this simpler solution: <Data>E-mail:<a href={'mailto:{email}'}>{email}</a></Data>. Thoughts? :)